# How to generate a 10Ghz signal?

Tags: rf, signal

I am a newbie to RF World. I need to know how to generate a 10Ghz sinusoidal wave. I have found this module:

https://pl.mouser.com/new/texas-instruments/ti-lmx2694epevm-eval-module/

Is it a good option for this purpose? Does this module need any other RF source?

what are other ways to generate Low phase noise oscillator? (10Ghz)

Comment: What are you going to do with your 10GHz signal?

Comment: What are your specs for f and phase noise and your budget?

Comment: It is a student project from my university. Maybe my professor could provide me about 2000$. F=10Ghz, phase noise better than -90dBc/Hz @ 1khz

Answer (score 4):

I'd consider using a VCO like [this one](https://synergymwave.com/products/vco/datasheet/DCYS8001600-5.pdf): -

[image]

[Link to Synergy VCOs](https://synergymwave.com/products/vco/).

It can be stabilized by using a phase-locked-loop and a lower reference frequency as in this example that uses a slightly different VCO (same type and manufacturer of course): -

[image]

- [Link to ADF4156](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4156.pdf).
- [Link to ADF5001](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF5001.pdf).

Comment: I appreciate your help and your comment. The mentioned circuit has phase noise level less than -50 dBc/Hz at 1Khz. Is there any other wave to have a 10Ghz with -90dBc/Hz at 1Khz?

Comment: Please link to the document that mentioned better than - 50 dB please.

Comment: Thank you, You can see the uploaded images (by yourself). the diagram shows that the phase noise is less than -40dB for all output frequencies.

Comment: A 10 GHz tone with -90 dBc/Hz SSB phase noise is a tall order. Even for dedicated test-and-measurement equipment, I suspect you will have to look at higher end, dedicated signal generators in order to achieve that under all circumstances.

Comment: @Parisa if you need better performance (performance not stated in question) then choose a better VCO. The point of this answer was to show what is possible. This topology (i.e. using a PLL) is probably going to give the best results for most applications but, if you are not too bothered about centre-frequency drift, look for a VCO that has much finer tuning and run it open loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for both comments Joren and Andy, what PLL do you suggest for creating a 100Mhz oscillator instead of using OCXO just VCO? ( I am going to multiply it to 100)

Comment: You don't use a PLL for generating a fixed frequency clock of 100 MHz. Any of [these from Farnell](https://uk.farnell.com/w/c/crystals-oscillators/oscillators/standard-oscillators/prl/results?st=oscillator%20100%20MHz) can produce 100 MHz. Of course you can just use 10 MHz and multiply by 1000. I used 10 MHz for the reference of a 600 MHz oscillator in a PLL setup but, of course with 10 GHz, you might prefer 100 MHz because it will lock-in more quickly.

Comment: @Parisa are you done with this question and answer now?

Comment: Thank you dear andy, Frankly, no, maybe I need a good reference (such as s book) that covers technical design tips for microwave oscillators.

Answer (score 3):

No, this device generates square wave outputs.

[image: block diagram]

[source: page 1 of the LMX2694 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snas785b/snas785b.pdf?ts=1598078460751&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMX2694-EP)

Notice the output buffers. They are used to generate a differential signal.

[image: waveform]

[source: page 7 of the LMX2694EPEVM Evaluation Instructions](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snau245/snau245.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-mousermode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1598078888926)

Comment: Thank you very much,Is there any other Chip for creating a 10Ghz sinusoidal signal?

Comment: @Parisa there are plenty of options, but you need to provide more information on your specific application.

Comment: Thank you. I need to create a signal generator with the phase noise of -90dBc/Hz (at 1Khz) for frequency range of 10Ghz to 13Ghz)

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, the way you generate a 10 GHz signal is the same as the way you generate a 1 GHz of 1 MHz signal - it's just that all the components become smaller.

The standard 'microwave' architectures still apply: you have a resonant network (be it a crystal, LC tank, transmission line resonator, dielectric resonator, etc...) and you compensate for the loss inside that resonator with a negative resistance (using an active devices such as transistor or diodes). The specifics depends on what your end-goal is. If you want a fixed frequency, you can use something like a dielectric resonator, crystal, or transmission line. These often offer high quality factors (which means low phase noise), but are impossible (or at least hard) to tune over a wide range.

When it comes to on-chip oscillators, I think one of the most common oscillator architectures is the differential-LC-tank. These are made by just cross-coupling a pair of transitors, and loading them with an LC tank.

This way you can make oscillators on ICs well beyond 10 GHz. The tuning can be done by replacing (or adding) the capacitors with a voltage-dependent capacitor.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Yes, you are right, But stability and phase noise is not acceptable for 10Ghz with this simple circuit.

Comment: If your goal is a single tone without any tuning, I suspect something like a DRO or similar high-Q resonator-based design is best. 

LC tanks can get good performance when coupled with a good PLL and stable, low frequency reference like a crystal, DRO, or similar.

Comment: In fact, the VCO on the texas instrument IC you suggested very likely uses some form of differential-LC tank. It's the loop of the PLL around it that can really lower the phase noise of the oscillator.

Comment: @Parisa, there is no phase noise requirement in the posted question. You should not be surprised that the answers don't address phase noise when it is not mentioned in the question asked.